# Python recursion with iterators

Tags: python, recursion

I have a question about python recursion functions.

I know functions can be easy replaced by loops/iterations but can you also use for/while statements in a recursion function and it's still recursive?

Comment: so u want a recursive function inside a for-loop inside a function?

Comment: I want a for loop inside a recursive function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Recursion simply means that a function is defined in terms of itself. It does not have any other restrictions on how a function is defined.

Consider e.g.:

```
def myLen(l):
  for i in range(3):
    print "Hello"

  return 1 + myLen(l[1:]) if l else 0
```

This is a recursive function despite the fact that it uses a `for` loop.

Comment: So it's still a recursive function if I use for loop?

Comment: @COntroke: Yes. It is recursive, because the definition of `myLen` involves a call to `myLen` itself. I.e. the function is defined in terms of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible:

```
def yop(x):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, x):
       result += yop(i-1)
    return result
```

Though, I'm not sure such a trivial answer will be helpful for the problem you're running into (unless you're simply curious whether this is possible). If you still have questions, it might be helpful to post a code example or more detailed description of the problem you're trying to solve.

Hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

yes,it is possible like that,

```
def fact(n):
    r=1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        r*=i
    return r

print fact(3)
```